# about "didReceiveRemoteNotification" delegate function

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

For system upper than iOS 10 version, within UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, there are two methods to clarify whether the APNS message method was called from user clicked or system received the message:

`- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler`

`- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(void))completionHandler`

While for system under iOS 10 version, there was an issue for the application delegate method `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo`,  there are 3 ways to call this method:

1:Click a notification message when App was running in background, will call this method.

2:Click App icon wether App was running in background or was killed, before App really launched(about 1~3 seconds), during these seconds if received an APNS message, this method will be called too.

3: App was running, pull down the notification bar to make application become inactive, at this state if received an APNS message, this method will be called too.

Now here is the question, how to judge these 3 kind of clicks? Generally if user did't click message to enter app(2 and 3's click), app shouldn't execute this message(like open a new page base on the message info). But how to know it is from 2 and 3?

From below answers, found that kind-2 has been resolved with the applicationState, while kind-3 still has left no answer, anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: I think under iOS 10 version does not work properly in a notification. please try above 10.if you try above iOS 10?

Answer (score 0):

You can check that using `UIApplication` state as the following:

```
///- if app is running in foreground
     if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {

         [self pushNotificationReceivedWhileActiveWithInfo:userInfo];

///- if app was running in background
     } else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
        if (self.pushReceivedWhileClosed != YES) {
         [self pushNotificationReceivedWhileInBackgroundWithInfo:userInfo];
       }
     }
```

Also you’ll need to handle the notification when the app was fully closed by getting it from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` when opened from a notification by saving the notification data and execute it when the user reaches the home screen let’s say:

```
     ///- when receiving push notification while [app closed]
     if (launchOptions != nil) {
         NSDictionary *dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
         if (dictionary != nil) {
             NSLog(@"[AppDelegate]##########################AppDelegate######################### Received notification while app CLOSED");

             ///- save the dictionary data and execute it when the app loads for example.
             self.pushReceivedWhileClosed = YES;
         }
     }
```

Comment: I've tried this before, but it didn't work. If received a remote push message just during the Application was about becoming active(click appIcon, at the same time push the testing message, make it happen almost at the same time), the applicationState was background and still handle this message as inactive, while I didn't click a message to make Application become active.

Comment: @fizix100 as far as I can tell , is that you can read the pending notifications from the system if ur using iOS 10 and later.

Comment: YES, the answer you mentioned worked on iOS 10 and later, not for lower system versions, that's why I ask the question on AppDelegate function `didReceiveRemoteNotification `, not for UserNotification delegate function on iOS 10 or later.

Answer (score 0):

Check the app state in the application didReceiveRemoteNotification

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground  )
    {
         //app was on background
    }
}
```

Comment: this wouldn't work for 3-way, whose state was also Inactive state. Generally for kind of 3-way, it should be treated as Active state

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

         NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];


               if (userInfo != nil)
                {
                    comingFromNotification = YES;
                }else{
                    comingFromNotification = NO;
                }

}
```